# How do I write a structure containing a dynamic allocated array to a binary file?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct SomeStruct{
    int id;
    int* dynamicArray;
};

int main(){
    struct SomeStruct test;
    test.id = 5;
    // allocate array
    test.dynamicArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    // save struct to a file
    FILE* handle = fopen("data", "wb");
    fwrite(&test, sizeof(test), 1, handle);
    fclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

After running this code the size of `data` file is 16 bytes.obviously an integer pointer has been written to the file instead of whole `dynamicArray` elements. How can I write such structure correctly in a file?

Comment: Write the data pointed to by `dynamicArray`, and not the struct, which contains the ***pointer to the data of the array***, and not the array itself.

Comment: You should create some simple format to store data. At least the dynamic array content should be stored in the file( more complicated if itself contains pointers), and a way to associate `SomeStruct` with that data in the format.

Comment: There is no merit in writing the pointer to file - you should write the data it points to. It would be advantageous for the `struct` to have a member `size_t size` so you know how much memory to allocate, and elements to read, when you reload the file later.

Comment: You keep track of how many entries are active in the array (or the max array size if you wish) and write that out after you write the id.  Might be nice to write out the number of used elements into the structure as well for ease of reading later...

Comment: Also consider how you would read the data back from a file, that should also hint to how you want to write the data.

Comment: Thanks for answers. seems this is not a good way for storing structures :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write the id.
2. Then write the array.

---

```
fwrite(&test.id, sizeof(test.id), 1, handle);
fwrite(test.dynamicArray , sizeof(test.dynamicArray[0]), 100, handle);
```

---

I want to point out that use of the hard coded number `100` is problematic.

1. You have to make sure that the read function also assumes that.
2. If you decide to change the number of elements allocated, you'll have to remember to go back to both places (the write and the read) to update them.

It will be better to store the size in the `struct` itself.

```
struct SomeStruct{
    int id;
    size_t size;
    int* dynamicArray;
};
```

and

```
test.id = 5;
test.size = 100;
// allocate array
test.dynamicArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*test.size);
```

Then you can update the write logic to:

```
fwrite(&test.id, sizeof(test.id), 1, handle);
fwrite(&test.size, sizeof(test.size), 1, handle);
fwrite(test.dynamicArray , sizeof(test.dynamicArray[0]), test.size, handle);
```

When you read the data back in, you will have the size information available to you and you can allocate the right amount memory for the `dynamicArray` member.

Comment: you are right. it should work. but as @Nit mentioned it is hard to read data back from file.